# Where can I ask a question regarding programming software that creates electronic circuits?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about how long it might take to program a piece of software that creates electronic circuit schematics and stuff. In order to answer the question, one needs to know how logic gates are built and how multiple levels of algorithmisation can save a lot of time and effort.

Should I ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), or [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: "how long it might take" - well, that sounds like a question which will attract very opinionated answers. Not sure if it's a good fit on either of those sites.

Comment: It is way too broad on any Stack Exchange site. You may have more luck on [the provoked blogging site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) (nothing prevents you from using the comments to provide sufficient context there - though most answerers won't read them as they are hidden by default).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say certainly not Super User, or for that matter, either other site.

Scope aside, the question can't really be answered.

> I have a question about how long it might take to program a piece of software that creates electronic circuit schematics and stuff.

Depends on the complexity of the software and how simple you want to make it to the end user. Also depends on your skills, and whether you're building off an existing circuit simulator or design software.

> In order to answer the question, one needs to know how logic gates are built and how multiple levels of algorithmisation can save a lot of time and effort.

And yes, often behind what seems like a 5 minute, or 5 month job, lies a lifetime of experience.

It’s not a good fit because the answer depends on a specific person's skills, and experience, as opposed to being able to be answered more generally.